# Apple Push Notification Implementation

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, push

I have an app in which i am trying to implement apns.
I am receiving the push on the device but unable to open the corresponding screen.

The scenario is that the application has a navigation bar as root view controller. It pushes some view controllers to login. If login is successful then it pushes a tab bar controller and hides itself. Now each tab bar controller has a navigation controller as its root view controller.

When i receive a push i want to open the 3rd tab but unable to ?

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

When you receive push notification, In that function you can make instance and save push notification page type and where create your tabbar, in that select   3 tab   using this code by if condtion

```
if (instancePage == 3){
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to controller (navigation and tab) so you have to switch between them 
[image]

Now You have to change root controller to show the tab bars
For example you get the push you make the tab controller the root controller

```
AppDelegate delegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
CommonTabViewController *controller=[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CommonTabViewController"];
    delegate.window.rootViewController=controller;
```

And after that you can change your tab bar with  `[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];`

Here is a screenshot of some part of my storyboard where i used it
[image]

Comment: but its build on storyboard so how can i change the root view controller to tab bar controller as i dont have the tab bar object

Comment: also when i get push i am not able to store it in appdelegate object as i logged the delegate object when tapped on pushed and it was nil. dont know if appdelegate starts after didreceivenotification gets called

Comment: tried this one working but now it is causing my first view controller viewdidload method to be called multiple times ... so this means when i make the tabbar controller as root view controller than viewdidload of my first view controller is called infinetly